# Speed of response of an sql query in a big mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I have a table in my database which has 300684 records and the problem is when i execute an sql query the response takes very long time so is there a solution for raising the time of response ? I work in phpmyadmin and i don't prefer to use another SGBD. Thank you

this is my query :

```
    SELECT * FROM `gipeord_conjoint` WHERE COD_AG in ( select PPR from 
gestion_delegation.dataidentifpersonnel)
```

the two tables `gipeord_conjoint` and `dataidentifpersonnel` are in two different database and this is the structure of the first one `gipeord_conjoint`:

```
COD_AG int
NUM_CONJ int
SIT_CONJ varchar
PRF_CONJ varcha
NAT_CONJ varchar
DOTI_CONJ int
CIN_CONJ varchar
```

and this is the structure of dataidentifpersonnel :

```
PPR int
CIN varchar
CD_POSITION varchar
CD_NATION varchar
CD_DIPS varchar
CD_DISCIP varchar
CD_STATUT varchar
```

...
...

Comment: 300K records is not very big for a database...but, there are so many factors into what could cause this (are you doing joins in your query, what kind of data makes up the columns, do you have proper indexes in place, are you using things like LIKE %xxx%), without seeing your query and table structure, not much help can be provided on this.

Comment: well, you should tell us more about your table schema (fields, indexes, ...) and show us your query. Hard to tell you how to optimise something we don't know anything about...

Comment: @Souad Well looking at your query, your going to wait forever to get values.

Comment: @souad don't post the query as comment, you can edit your question!

Comment: Ok see my question above

Comment: What is *a very long time* ? Don't forget your on the web. Is the database local ? Also **NEVER** use select *

Comment: the database is local. do you mean that i should write all names of fields instead * ?

Comment: Yes exactly. Long story short. Imagine you change the database design in a month. Don't remember you used Select * but still add a column you **don't want in your returned dataset** . I can only imagine the damages...

Comment: I tried  **SELECT `COD_AG` FROM `gipeord_conjoint` WHERE `COD_AG` in ( select `PPR` from `gestion_delegation`.`dataidentifpersonnel`);** and no answer too !

Comment: Have you tried an `OUTER JOIN` instead of `sub-query`?  Have you set-up any indexes?

Comment: I try **SELECT `COD_AG`,`NUM_CONJ`,`SIT_CONJ`,`PRF_CONJ`,`NAT_CONJ`,`NOM_PR_CONJ`,`DOTI_CONJ`,`CIN_A_CONJ`,`CIN_N_CONJ`,`DAT_SIT_CONJ` FROM `gipeord_conjoint` WHERE `gipeord_conjoint`.`COD_AG`=`gestion_delegation`.`dataidentifpersonnel`.`PPR`;** but I have this error : `#1054 - Unknown column 'gestion_delegation.dataidentifpersonnel.PPR' in 'where clause'`

Comment: OPS! I forgot the second table in where clause. The right query is : 


**SELECT COD_AG,NUM_CONJ,SIT_CONJ,PRF_CONJ,NAT_CONJ,NOM_PR_CONJ,DOTI_CONJ,‌​CIN_A_CONJ,CIN_N_CONJ,DAT_SIT_CONJ FROM gipeord_conjoint,gestion_delegation.dataidentifpersonnel WHERE gipeord_conjoint.COD_AG=gestion_delegation.dataidentifpersonnel.PPR;**

I get now my data . Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

**Never... use Select *... EVER.**

---

This is like saying :

> Hi my computer is slower than usual can you explain why ?

You need to show us your query if you want more specific help from our part.

As for your current case, 300,684 records is not that much so it's not a reason to have a slow query.

*Off the top of my head* :

- Your  query could be not-optimized. Take a look at the [execution plan](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/). (I'd look for table scans)
- Make sure you have proper indexes.
- Take a look at how many people are running requests at the same time.
- Check who's querying the database and where is the query comming from.

Add your query so I can help more.

Comment: my database is used by me only. I added the query in the question after  editing.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.6 changed the optimization method for `in` in the `where` clause (as explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/semi-joins.html)).

If you are using an earlier version of MySQL, then it is executing the subquery in the `in` for every row in the output.  You can fix this by changing the `in` to an `exists` clause:

```
select gc.*
FROM `gipeord_conjoint` gc
WHERE exists (select 1 from gestion_delegation.dataidentifpersonnel dip where dip.PPR = gc.COD_AG)
```

This will be even faster with an index on `gestion_delegation.dataidentifpersonnel(PPR)`.