# SQL query performance and pagination

Tags: sql

i have a few thousand rows of data and i'm connecting to the db via VPN.
retreiving data over VPN is pretty slow and i'm looking for ways to 
improve performance.  is pagination of results a good way to go?

Comment: yes. LIMIT AND OFFSET should works for you.

Comment: First of all, you should read the [FAQ]. This question show **no proof of research at all**. You've asked 13 questions on this site you should start to know how it works by now...

Comment: This is so vague. Basically any solution that will minimize the amount of data that is being sent from the client (you) to the server will do. Yes, pagination is one of them.

Comment: Have you considered that your connection might be the problem?  Thousands of rows shouldn't be an issue (using a client like SQL Server Management Studio or the equivalent).  But if you're going over a 100kps connection, it'll always be slow.

Comment: @Jeff i think connecting over VPN is a part of the problem because it's fine over the network.  i was told it's probably not the connection and should look at other ways to improve performance.
that's why i decided to ask this stupid question.

Answer (score 2):

It always depends on how you are using pagination. If you are returning all the data and only displaying 10 rows at a time on the client then it would not change anything. If you are truly getting only 10 records at a time from the DB then it could help. However 1000's of rows should be nothing for any database platform or any network connection to provide. I would look into the query to ensure it is optimized.

Comment: @milesmiles55 You can refer to [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16484918/1063093) as for how to check if your query is optimized.(With no information from you part)

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk there is plenty of information in my initial post. 'select *' is not in my vocabulary.  no where in your posted answer is the term 'pagination'. why?

Comment: First, you provided little to No information. Talking about query performance and not even showing parts of the query... Anyway read correctly. The answer is about you pagination. I commented to add a link where it is explained **how to check if your query is well. optimized** while you provided no information. Select * might not be your case, it was for the OP of the question I answered. How can I know you didn't show your code